# including opencv libraries with qtsdk 1.2.1

Tags: qt, opencv

I have been struggling recently to get opencv to work with qt. At this moment my issue is this: It cant find the libraries. No matter what I do it says the same thing:

> :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_improc245d.lib'

I included the bin in my path variable, and added each file to libs:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\opencv\\build\\include

LIBS += -LC:\\OpenCV-2.4.5\\mybuild\\lib\\Debug \

    -lopencv_calib3d245d \
    -lopencv_contrib245d \
    -lopencv_core245d \
    -lopencv_features2d245d \
    -lopencv_flann245d \
    -lopencv_gpu245d \
    -lopencv_highgui245d \
    -lopencv_improc245d \
    -lopencv_legacy245d \
    -lopencv_ ml245d \
    -lopencv_ objdetect245d \
    -lopencv_ ts245d \
    -lopencv_ video245d
```

also, my opencv library is compiled from source for msvc2010 with qt enabled, and my qt is using msvc2010 as it's compiler.

Am I adding the libraries wrong or is something wrong with my includepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the leftmost pane of Qt Creator. There is a Projects tab. (ctrl+5) should reach you there. Go to Build Environment. Click on Details to get list of System Environment Variables. Goto INCLUDE variable in the list. Select and click Edit. Add path_to_opencv/opencv/build/include.

[ path_to_opencv is the path where your opencv directory resides.]

Clean the project, run qmake and build the project again.